# get format of image and videos in visual basic

Tags: image, vba, video, powerpoint

I have some images and videos in my powerpoint presentation. Depends of what format have each one (jpg, mp3, jpeg,...) I want it to make a different thing so I need to know what kind of file is it. Is there anything in Visual Basic to make it?

EDITED

I want to difference the images and videos supported by iPad with the ones that are not supported. That is why I need to know the format of them.

Comment: are they simple embedded or embedded with links to original files?

Comment: The ones that I am using right now are simple embedded but it would be great to know how to make in both ways :)

Comment: Try to use `Shape.Type` property to get one out of approx. 20 possible types of shapes. You can additionally use 'Shape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName` property for linked shapes to check file extension. If you need some more information please give more information in your question (about possible types and action you would run depending on type of Shape).

Comment: I put a little bit more info about what I want to do. I am already using Shape.Type to know if it is an image or video... But I also need to know what format has each image or video. 'Shape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName` is not working because I am not using linked shapes but if you know how to do it for normal files (attached from my computer) could be a solution. Thanks!

Comment: At the moment I have only idea for files which I linked, no idea how to do it for embedded ones.

Comment: with Shape.Name I get the name of the file but no the extension... it would be possible to make the extension appear?

Comment: See answer for linked file...

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: to state it clear- solution below works only with shapes which are linked to files!**

```
Function WhatTypeOfMedia(SHP As Shape)

    Select Case Right(SHP.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, 4)
        Case ".jpg", "jpeg"
            WhatTypeOfMedia = "Picture type"
        Case ".wav", ".mp3"
            WhatTypeOfMedia = "Music type"
        '... end other possible types put here
    End Select
End Function
```

To make a test run for 1st slide of active presentation try this code:

```
Sub Take_format_Linked()

    On Error Resume Next    'required for these files which are not linked
    Dim SHP As Shape
    For Each SHP In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
    '1st check if format is linked- best option:
    If Len(SHP.LinkFormat.SourceFullName) > 0 Then
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
        'if so, let's call function
            Debug.Print WhatTypeOfMedia(SHP)
        'here you can do what you want based on function result
        Else
            Err.Clear
        End If
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

As a result you get information in Immediate window which shape is which type. You could use that types to run what you need in main sub. 
In that simple idea I kept `On Error Resume Next` to avoid error if Shape is not linked.

Comment: This one works only for linked ones... I need for the normal ones. If there is for linked for the normal ones also should be something.

Comment: Which is exactly said at the beginning of my answer and in comment below your question!

Comment: Do you already have this presentation or you will create it?? I don't think there is any solution for embedded not linked shapes. I couldn't find...

Comment: I am making it as a template for other presentations because I want to migrate it to the iPad... But I don't know how I am going to do it if I cannot differentiate the format that it supports... :( Anyway thanks for your help!!

Comment: One suggestion for future presentation. You could use `.Tags` parameters for each shape which you would place in next presentations. Put in tag information about file type or/and extension and use it for further checks... If you find anything other for shapes which already exists please present your answer here...

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, you can get the file types for linked files, but there's no way to get them for embedded files. However, if you don't need to do it in VBA or can manipulate ZIP files in VBA, open the PPTX as a zip and look for the media folder.  There you'll find any embedded files (pictures, sounds, movies).

They may not be in the same format as they originally were in; PPT sometimes converts images when it imports them.  But that shouldn't be an issue considering what you're after.