# Delete specific image file types

Tags: vba, powerpoint, file-type

Suppose I wanted to delete specific type files, like JPEG images across specific slides; not sure how to go about this; this what I'm using:

```
Dim osld As Slide
   Dim opic As Shape
   Dim lngCount As Long
   On Error GoTo err
   err.Clear
   For Each osld In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
      For lngCount = osld.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
         Set opic = osld.Shapes(lngCount)
         Select Case opic.Type
         Case Is = msoBlogImageTypeJPEG
            opic.Delete
         End Select
      Next lngCount
   Next osld
   Exit Sub
err:
   MsgBox "Did you select slides?"
End Sub
```

Comment: And what's the specific problem you're having with that?  Or are you asking if there's a better way?

Comment: Hey Tim, it doesn't work; it won't pick up the JPEG file type. I tried to achieve that using the msoblogtypejpeg, but it doesnt work :/

Comment: What type do you get on an known jpeg? (In the `MsoShapeType` enumeration is msoBlogImageTypeJPEG not included)

Comment: `MsoShapeType` doesn't include *any* values which appear to match to file formats such as jpg/png/gif etc.

Comment: Shape.Type only tells you whether the shape is a placeholder, a picture, or other shape type. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype If the images are _linked_, you can get the original file ending from the first answer on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988487/get-format-of-image-and-videos-in-visual-basic If the images are _embedded_, there's no good way to get the image format with VBA.

Comment: my goal is really to have a macro delete specific images; i figured, well if I can have the Macro identify JPEG images and delete those, and set the images I want to keep in PNG or some other format, but this is a round about way of doing that task. I didn't want to write a macro listing every shape I wanted it to delete, only specific ones, if that makes sense

Comment: So (correct me if I'm misinterpreting) you want a way to delete all images *except* those you've marked as "keepers" in some way. The actual format of the image files is not really the concern here other than as a potential way of identifying the ones to keep (but a way that wouldn't work). Would another method that allowed you to select and somehow tag the "keepers" paired with another routine that deleted all the non-keepers work for you?

Comment: Steve, that's exactly right! The file format was just some round about way of achieving exactly what you've stated,